# 401 Unauthorised when processing a Webhook

Tags: next.js, webhooks, ngrok, next.js13, clerk

I'm trying to process a webhook sent by the auth provider Clerk when a user is created. In order to test this procedure locally, I tried localtunnel which did not work and then ngrok.
When the webhook is sent to the `https://13f1-...-859.ngrok-free.app/api/webhooks/clerk` provided from ngrok I get the following output:

```
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
https://13f1-...-859.ngrok-free.app -> http://localhost:3000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              5       0       0.00    0.00    0.03    0.04
HTTP Requests
-------------

POST /api/webhooks/clerk                401 Unauthorized
```

Using Nextjs13's new app router, I wrote the following route to handle the webhook:

(app/api/webhooks/clerk/route.ts):

```
import { db } from "@/db/db";
import { playlists, users } from "@/db/schema";
import type { User } from "@clerk/nextjs/api";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { eq, isNull, inArray } from "drizzle-orm";

type UnwantedKeys = "primaryEmailAddressId" | "primaryPhoneNumberId" | "phoneNumbers";

interface UserInterface extends Omit<User, UnwantedKeys> {
    email_addresses: {
        email_address: string;
        id: string;
    }[];
    primary_email_address_id: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    primary_phone_number_id: string;
    phone_numbers: {
        phone_number: string;
        id: string;
    }[];
}

const webhookSecret: string = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET || "";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    const payload = await req.json()
    const payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);
    const headerPayload = headers();
    const svixId = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
    const svixIdTimeStamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
    const svixSignature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");
    if (!svixId || !svixIdTimeStamp || !svixSignature) {
        console.log("svixId", svixId)
        console.log("svixIdTimeStamp", svixIdTimeStamp)
        console.log("svixSignature", svixSignature)
        return new Response("Error occured", {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
    const svixHeaders = {
        "svix-id": svixId,
        "svix-timestamp": svixIdTimeStamp,
        "svix-signature": svixSignature,
    };
    const wh = new Webhook(webhookSecret);
    let evt: Event | null = null;
    try {
        evt = wh.verify(payloadString, svixHeaders) as Event;
    } catch (_) {
        console.log("error")
        return new Response("Error occured", {
            status: 400,
        })
    }
    // Handle the webhook
    const eventType: EventType = evt.type;
    const { id, first_name, last_name, emailAddresses } = evt.data;
    if (eventType === "user.created") {
        const email = emailAddresses[0].emailAddress;
        try {
            await db.insert(users).values({
                id,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                email,
            });
            return new Response("OK", { status: 200 });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return new Response("Error handling user creation in the database", {
                status: 400,
            })
        }
    } else if (eventType == "user.deleted") {
        try {
            await db.delete(users).where(eq(users.id, id));
            const recordsToDelete = (await db.select().from(playlists).leftJoin(users, eq(playlists.user_id, users.id)).where(isNull(users.id)));
            const idsToDelete = recordsToDelete.map(record => record.playlists.id);
            await db
                .delete(playlists).where(inArray(playlists.id, idsToDelete));
            return new Response("OK", { status: 200 });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            throw new Error(`Failed to insert user into database`);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("eventType", eventType)
        return new Response("Invalid event type", {
            status: 201,
        })
    }
}


type Event = {
    data: UserInterface;
    object: "event";
    type: EventType;
};

type EventType = "user.created" | "user.deleted" | "*";
```

Answer (score 3):

Restart your ngrok agent by running the command, replacing {ws endpoint signing secret} with the Webhook endpoint signing secret: **ngrok http 3000 --verify-webhook clerk --verify-webhook-secret {ws endpoint signing secret}**

from this guide: https://ngrok.com/docs/integrations/clerk/webhooks/#security

they have updated ngrok agent, so you might update your local agent's version too. you can do this by starting the old agent with default command: **ngrok http 3000**. and see the upgrade message in CLI.

**What actually worked for me:**

- last version of Next.js with Server Components and App folder. previously I was on older version with Pages folder.
- make my WS endpoint public in middleware.ts:

```
export default authMiddleware({
    publicRoutes: ["/api/webhooks/clerk"]
});
```

- problem wasn't with ngrok it works fine with: `ngrok http 3000`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although this might seem the most viable solution for the problem, I still got an unauthorized response. I've tried alternative solutions such as localtunnel however didn't work as well. It might be my machine...

Comment: @Braz I'm facing this issue too, so I wrote to the support. Try to do it too. Anyway, I will ping you in case of resolution.

Comment: some tips: look at the answer provided by @Hassan El-Amin below, make sure your webhook endpoint is a public route; be sure that you are using Server Components and App folder feature provided by last version of next.js; if you still struggle try to host your app on Vercel and test it there, don't forget to make change in Clerk WS endpoint settings.

Answer (score 0):

this is my /webhooks/user/route file

```
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from "http";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { Webhook, WebhookRequiredHeaders } from "svix";

type EventType = "user.created" | "user.updated" | "*";

type Event = {
    data: Record<string, string | number>,
    object: "event",
    type: EventType,
};

const webhookSecret = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET || "";

// console.log(`Webhook secret: ${webhookSecret}`);

async function handler(request: Request) {
    try {
        const payload = await request.json();
        const headersList = request.headers;
        const heads = {
            "svix-id": headersList.get("svix-id"),
            "svix-timestamp": headersList.get("svix-timestamp"),
            "svix-signature": headersList.get("svix-signature"),
        };

        const wh = new Webhook(webhookSecret);
        let evt: Event | null = null;

        try {
            evt = wh.verify(
                JSON.stringify(payload),
                heads as IncomingHttpHeaders & WebhookRequiredHeaders
            ) as Event;
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Verification error: ${(err as Error).message}`);
            console.error(err);
            return NextResponse.json({}, { status: 400 });
        }

        const eventType: EventType = evt.type;
        if (eventType === "user.created" || eventType === "user.updated") {
            const { id, ...attributes } = evt.data;
            // console.log(id);
            // console.log(attributes);
        }

        // Added this line to return a response in case of no errors
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Handled successfully' }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Unexpected error: ${err}`);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Something went wrong' }, { status: 500 });
    }
}


export const GET = handler;
export const POST = handler;
export const PUT = handler;
```

---

// I defined the Clerk middleware function as such to enable the API route as a public route, so that it is not being blocked by CLerk middleware

```
const clerkAuth = clerkAuthMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/", "/admin", "/api/webhooks/user"]
});
```

---

then used this for ngork instead

```
ngrok http 3000 --verify-webhook clerk --verify-webhook-secret {endpoint signing secret}
```

---

Make sure your Clerk Webhook is set the right Ngork url

Comment: What version of ngrok are you using? I'm constantly getting this error: https://ngrok.com/docs/errors/err_ngrok_3204/

Comment: I am using ngrok version 3.3.1. Try and set your clerk middleware to debug mode to try and narrow the issue down. Something like this:

authMiddleware({debug: true});

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a while, albeit with NextJS 13.4.2 Pages Router.  Banged my head around for a while - turned out it was my **middleware.ts** setup.

export const config was not registering my publicRoute or ignoredRoutes.  Very weird issue but got it working now.

Maybe some newb mistake but I couldn't find a solution online so thought I would share.

This is all tested on my local development server with **ngrok http 3000** to tunnel it to an online host so my webhook can work.  Not tested in production.  ngrok v3.3.4, free plan.

/src/middleware.ts below

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
export default authMiddleware({ 
  ignoredRoutes: ["/((?!api|trpc))(_next|.+\..+)(.*)"],  
  publicRoutes: ["/api/webhooks/user/route"],
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};
```

/pages/api/webhooks/user/route.ts below

```
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from "http";
import type { WebhookEvent } from "@clerk/clerk-sdk-node";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { Webhook, WebhookRequiredHeaders } from "svix";
// FROM https://github.com/clerkinc/clerk-nextjs-examples/blob/main/examples/widget/pages/api/webhooks/user.ts

type NextApiRequestWithSvixRequiredHeaders = NextApiRequest & {
    headers: IncomingHttpHeaders & WebhookRequiredHeaders;
};



// Disable the bodyParser so we can access the raw
// request body for verification.
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

async function buffer(readable: NextApiRequestWithSvixRequiredHeaders) {
    const chunks = [];
    for await (const chunk of readable) {
        chunks.push(typeof chunk === 'string' ? Buffer.from(chunk) : chunk);
    }

    return Buffer.concat(chunks);
}

if (!process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error("WEBHOOK_SECRET is not set.");
}

const webhookSecret: string = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET || "";

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequestWithSvixRequiredHeaders, res: NextApiResponse) {
    console.log("got hit at wh")
    // Verify the webhook signature
    // See https://docs.svix.com/receiving/verifying-payloads/how
    const payload = (await buffer(req)).toString();
    console.log(payload, "payload")
    const headers = req.headers;
    const wh = new Webhook(webhookSecret);
    let evt: WebhookEvent | null = null;

    try {
        evt = wh.verify(payload, headers) as WebhookEvent;
    } catch (_) {
        return res.status(400).json({});
    }

    // Handle the webhook
    const eventType = evt.type;
    // console.log(eventType);

    res.json({});
}
```

**Note**: *async function buffer()* was from another stackoverflow answer... can't seem to find the post.  This is supposed to help with deploying to serverless Vercel.  TBD.